# Installing the Keycloak client adapter in Wildfly domain mode

Tags: wildfly, keycloak

I'm implementing keycloak as authentication administrator of my applications, I have followed the respective manuals

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/getting_started/index.html#securing-a-jboss-servlet-application

In section 4.2 Installing the Client Adapter

My application server is a wildfly 17 and that documentation works well on standalone servers (full, ha)

The problem I have that my servers in Wildfly production are in domain mode (one master and two slaves), and the installation of those adapters does not work.

How can I install this adapter in domain mode on wildfly?

Answer (score 0):

1 - download and extract keycloak adapter in domain controller and all host controllers

2 - manual config domain.xml "only in domain controller"

```
<domain xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:10.0">
   <extension module="org.keycloak.keycloak-adapter-subsystem"/>
    .....

   <profile name="full-ha">
            <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak:1.1"/>
    .....
           <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:2.0">
                <security-domains>
                   <security-domain name="keycloak">
                     <authentication>
                         <login-module 
                         code="org.keycloak.adapters.jboss.KeycloakLoginModule" 
                         flag="required"/>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
   .......
                </security-domains>
           </subsystem>
   .......
  </profile>
```

sample [domain.xml](https://gofile.io/?c=qqEYTV)

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cb6c.png)